# Django dynamically filled dropdown in form

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a form to have a dropdown whose contents change dynamically according to user.  I can get the dropdown to change for all users, but not for individuals.

I've got this form:

forms.py:

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model  = Candidate

        fields = (
            'name',
            'foos',
        )

        labels = {
            'name'   :_('Name'),
            'foos'   :_('Chosen Foos'),
        }

        widgets = {
            'name' : TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),
            'foos' : SelectMultiple(),
        }
```

models.py:

```
class UserInfo (models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length = 256, blank = True, default = None)

    foos  = models.ManyToManyField(Foogroup, blank = True)
```

If I use this as is, I get a dropdown filled with all the possible values of Foogroup.

If I give FooForm an **init**(), I can set the dropdown to have a set of values, but that's setting the values for everyone.

How can I dynamically set the contents of the dropdown to just what has been set for User Bob, while User Mary gets just those contents that have been set for her?

I'm thinking something like this may work:

ajax.py:

```
def chooseFoos(request):

    if request.method != POST:

        ### 1. do magic to get handle to form's dropdown ###

        ### 2. fill form's dropdown for request.POST['name'] ###

        ### 3. highlight a particular entry in the new dropdown ###

    else:
        ...
```

I don't know how to do the bits in step 1 or step 3 of chooseFoos().

I've tried building a response that is then JSON-encoded into an HttpResponse. That works for 'name', but is ignored for 'foos'.

Thanks for the help.